# Getting Unicode of text entered in regional language in JTextArea (Java)

Tags: java, unicode

I am building an app where I want user to input text in some other my regional language which I have achieved by changing its Font. Now but at backend I want that its Unicode to be extracted but how could I achieve it ..?? If I copies that string and enter it anywhere its just the English language ..?? How do Java gets to know about the language..??

This is the code :-

```
 /* some code */   
    static Font f4=new Font("AnmolLipiThick",Font.BOLD ,15);
/* some code */
                ta = new JTextArea();
                //ta.setFont(f2);
                ta.setFont(f4);
                //ta.setWrapStyleWord(false);
                ta.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
                ta.setLineWrap(true);
                c.gridy = 2;
                c.weighty = 0.4;
                c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;           
                frame.add(ta,c);
/* some code */
```

Such  as in my above java code the font is for Punjabi language..!! How could Java get to know about that such that it starts Unicode from that code plane...!! How to achieve it plz help me out..??

Comment: I am searching the code,asap I will find,I will post.

Comment: plz guys,,is there someone who can atleast have hints on it..!!

Comment: Plz guy you are so unclear...

Comment: hmm,,,,@beny1700 what is unclear bro..I hope ques is quite clear that there is text area in which user can type in different language such as french,japanese, punjabi(in my case). I simple want mechanism by which java could understand the language user is typing and extract its unicode..!! Now is something still left unclear..??

Answer (score 0):

```
 <p align=right><div id="google_translate_element"></div><script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: 
google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script><script type="text/javascript"        

 src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit">
 </script>
</p>

 Try with it if still not able to get it plz comment below,I am still need a
lot of    searching because I have forget where I have put that file.
```

Comment: here u r using online tool if I am not wrong,,but plz read my comment above..!!

Comment: Very Busy in Office,I will try to help you when I will get some free time.

Answer (score 0):

It is practically impossible to understand what you want at the moment of writing this.. However, I'll take a stab in the dark and hopefully what I say can help you..

Characters in Java is 2 bytes each. Each byte can hold a code-point or both can hold a single code-point. Java's chars are thus UTF-16 encoded. If the character's code-point is greater than `0xFFFF` then it will be encoded with 2 chars (surrogate pairs)

You can read here for more on handling this: http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/supplementary-142654.html

TLDR (You'll need these):

```
Character.toCodePoint(char high, char low)
Character.toChars(int codePoint)
Character.codePointAt(char[] a, int index)
Character.isHighSurrogate(char ch)
Character.isLowSurrogate(char ch)
Character.isLetter(int codePoint)
Character.isValidCodePoint
```

And if you ever need to use native strings:

Then you can pass then back and forth to Java like so:

```
void Java_natives_toUTF8(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jstring utf16)
{
    const char* utf8 = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(env->GetStringUTFChars(utf16, NULL));

    //Do whatever with utf8.. it is UTF8 format.

    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(utf8, reinterpret_cast<const char*>(utf16));
}
```

Comment: hmm,,,I think ques is simple I have a textArea where user can enter text in different language.eg spainish,french,punjabi(in my case) by just seting the font . I want mechanism by which Java gets to know about the language in which user is typing and can then extract the code..!!